# what is the OSX version of Linux's /dev/usb/lp0?

Tags: linux, macos, usb, device

I'm writing to a centronics cable and blinking some LEDs via a simple "bufferized" circuit.

I'm able to write out the bits via C code referencing the device location on /dev/usb/lp0 on an Ubuntu machine.

However, I'd like to be able to do this on OSX Mavericks.  I don't see the same type of device file as I do in Linux.

i.e. is there an OSX analog to /dev/usb/lp0 on Linux?

Thanks much.

Comment: What type of USB/parallel adapter are you using? Is it possible that it requires drivers to be installed?

Comment: it's made by Sabrent and it uses IEEE 1284 protocol (type A: 25 pin connector)

Comment: Are you sure it's even supported on Mac OS X? [The web page I found](http://www.sabrent.com/category/cables/USB-DB25F/) does say it's "Mac OS X compatible", but it doesn't list any system requirements, and the matching logo doesn't appear on the box.

Answer (score 0):

Under the concept of "everything's a file" lp0 is just a special file that allows raw access to a device, in this case a 'special character file' for the first parallel device.  The same would exist on OSX if a driver was present that matched the device, or something like `/dev/parport0`.  OSX has a pretty limited collection of parallel drivers though.  You could try to fudge it - create a 'character' device file pointing it to some generic parallel driver with `mknod`.

e.g. `mknod lp0 c x y` where x an y are the major and minor numbers for the device type.  Typically you find these numbers in the `documentation/devices.txt` file on linux, not sure where this info is on OSX though.

I've seen devices handle this using generic printer drivers, such as a "gadget printer":
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/gadget_printer.txt

(my initial assumption)

In this case the device will actually show up on the system as a printer.  You can find a list of printers and their location using CUPS utilities like lpstat:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/lpstat.1.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/1/lpstat

There's also the environment variables *LPDEST* and *PRINTER* which should list the default print location:

`echo $LDPEST`

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the question. The goal is driving a piece of hardware connected to a USB parallel port adapter, but that device is **not** a printer. CUPS won't do a whit of good.

Comment: I know the type of device he is referring to, they use the linux printer interface instead of creating a proper device driver. You just treat it like a printer and send commands to it as you would content to print with something like lp. What i though he was trying to find is where this virtual device is mounted in osx.  Lpstat would list all print devices and their corresponding mount and it was mounting to lp0 suggesting it was the only print device in the system, in which case $lpdest or $printer should provide the path he needs to target in his code. It is a printer from sys point of view.

Comment: I was under the impression he's got a custom circuit board he's connected with a usb to parallel cable and on linux this gets mounted as a printer.  He is then using the raw print device to send instructions to it (the device you'd target with an lp command). Assuming osx also treats it as a printer he needs to find the mount location of the raw "print" device which is exactly what CUPS utilities will help with.

Comment: If it shows up as a USB printer, he's simply out of luck. The type of device he's trying to interface with is basically treating the parallel port as a GPIO interface. Trying to treat it as a printer (basically a wide serial port) won't work.